# Color issues from photoshop to android

Tags: android, colors, photoshop

I have created some images and set some colors using photoshop and applied them to our app in android studio, but for the same hex code, colors arent same, I do not understand why this is happening. I took a screen shot of the color im working in photoshop and then opened the image in photoshop, surprisingly the color code changed, and it was same as android studio was showing and its not the actual color, I have even checked the RGB/ CMYK mode, it is in RGB mode, i even tried CMYK mode, in the both the cases the problem persists. No matter how many times i have tried, the problem persists. Please help me out

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Rodrigo, you should set a color workflow.

If you are mainly working on documents viewed on the web or mobile devices :
1) in Photoshop go to **Edit>Colors Settings** and set your **RGB Colorspace** to "sRGB".
2) Make sure **Proof Colors** is unchecked in the **View** menu.
3) Make sure your document has the "sRGB" color profile attributed (can be fixed by using "Attribute color profile" or "Convert color profile" in the **Edit** menu).

This should ensure color consistency across most devices and web browsers.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would try that.

Answer (score 0):

It very strongly depends on device screen. I have 4 devices, and colors are different on all of them

Comment: ya, its with different devices, but im using iMAC, i made a 9 patch image in photoshop and pasted the exact image in android studio,then it appeared as little bit different color then i checked with android color picker its showing a different color code from which i used in photoshop

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your color profile in photoshop, by default photoshop gives you different colors when you save for web. Check out this tutorial step by step and let me know if this fixed your problem.

http://viget.com/inspire/the-mysterious-save-for-web-color-shift

Comment: Thank you so much, I would try that.